# BGP Community Policy to only allow single Community tagged routes

Tags: cisco, bgp, cisco-ios-xr, route-filter

I have a requirement to do a Cisco IOS-XR Route-policy to allow only routes that have a single community tagged and not allow routes with multiple community tags.

I built a lab that has two routes:

- 10.70.151.1/32 - Has a tag of 64555:100
- 10.70.151.2/32 - Has a tag of 64555:100 and 64555:200

I tried this policy but both routes keep getting passed and I just need the first route to pass :

```
route-policy ALLOW_SINGLE_COMM
  if community matches-every (ios-regex '^64555:100$') then
    pass
  else
    drop
  endif
end-policy
```

Below is some outputs:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you applying the policy? We need to see more of your configuration, for example, the entire BGP configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ron..i have updated the question.

Comment: Does that route actually show up in the routing table? BGP is receiving the prefix, so it will be in the BGP table. Applying that outbound from the other router would prevent it from being sent and received, but I think anything received will end up in the BGP table, but not necessarily the routing table.

Comment: Also, try clearing all BGP prefixes, so that it must reload the prefixes from its peer.

Comment: Hi Ron, I have tried clearing the bgp neighbors. The route still shows up in routing table on the receiving router, even though there is an inbound route policy as per the config.

Comment: Did you try to apply it outbound on the other router? I'm not very familiar with IOS-XR, but it is worth a try to see if the policy works. The sending router should then not send it, and you will need to clear BGP on the receiving router.

Comment: Yep, tried outbound on the other router and no luck either. The issue is the policy itself. I can't figure out how to make the policy pass only if it matches the community exactly. The logic and documentation says as long as there is a match it will pass. I need to make it match only if all communities match. Kind of like an as.path for communities.

Comment: OK, then wait for someone more familiar with IOS-XR. We have them pop up here, but I would need something to play with, and I do not have any IOS-XR devices here.

Comment: If you could get it to work on IOS I am sure I could convert the config.

Comment: Well, I'm stuck at home (nobody goes into the office, at least until July 1, at which time the situation will be reevaluated). I only have one Cisco router here. I was moved to the automation group, so I do not have remote access to the labs anymore. Once in a while I can get one of the engineers with equipment on the bench to let me play with something, but I do not know who is doing what right now since I'm no longer in that group.

Comment: I found something similar, but the formatting will suck in a comment: neighbor PEER_GROUP route-map FROM_FROM_PEER1 in
!
ip bgp-community new-format
ip community-list expanded IN_ROUTES permit 65000:*
ip community-list expanded IN_ROUTES permit 65001:*
!
route-map FROM_PEER1 permit 10
 match community IN_ROUTES
!

Comment: Have you tried matching a community-set?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Logged a Case with Cisco and the RPL developer has confirmed you cannot only match a single part of a community string, it  will always evaluate the whole community string, so can't be done.